# Cannot Activate Apache SSL (HTTPS Configuration)

Tags: server, 14.04, apache2, ssl, https

I've newly installed my private web server with Ubuntu 14.04 and I installed already Apache 2.4.7.

When I open via Firefox http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (my IP adress) I see the "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page" which indicates that Apache works. So far so good.

I want to use SSL so I want configure Apache for that.

I followed the documentation (chapter "HTTPS Configuration").
https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/httpd.html#https-configuration

There are 3 commands I have to run in Terminal and I did so. If I understand the documentation right this should work without creating own certificate.

So to test I open again Firefox https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx to check if it works. But the page seems to hang and it doesn't seem to work.

Questions:

- What is wrong?
- Do I have to create a certificate before I can use the default-ssl site?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

SSL requires certificates, so you have to create/get one before you can run an https server. And I'm sure there will be error messages in the apache log files about the problem.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for answer. Here is the error message: [Wed Apr 30 19:26:57.561203 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 3472] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for localhost:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: In linked documentation is written the following: "The default HTTPS configuration will use a certificate and key generated by the ssl-cert package. They are good for testing, but the auto-generated certificate and key should be replaced by a certificate specific to the site or server."

Comment: Yes, you need a certificate which has in the common name or subject alternative name the host name. But this is usually only a problem for the client, which will not accept the certificate - maybe this is what you mean with "doesn't seem to work?", it's hard to tell without having detailed error descriptions.

Comment: Hey Steffen. Thanks for feedback again. Actually I don't know what you expect as detailed error description. I explain a little bit more. I have a dyndns applied. That means when I open from an another computer the address http://myserver.com I see the Apache page. After configuring HTTPS I expect to find my server via https:// instead. But page isn't found then. So so what can I do? Generating my own certificate with following description ? https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html